# MySQL: Error 1045 - how to set correct rules?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL db and need to create a new database. However, I can not do it since I keep getting the 1045 Error.

```
show grants
```

shows following:

```
Grants for user@host
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*C1B4F8E5221061DBEE23A2E3256B77F2744D5CA7'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* TO 'user'@'host'
```

I don't even have enough rights for rewoking and granting or creating a new user. Could you please help me what to do?

Comment: If you do not have the required privileges to create a database, then you simply cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have privileges on a schema named `db`. You can't use other schemas, nor can you create new schemas.

The way to resolve his is to talk to your database administrator. Either get them to grant you privilege to create new schemas, or else get them to just create the one new schema you want, and grant you privileges on that schema.